# How does one pixelate an rgb output in material?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine

i really wanted to make a pixelated shading effect in eevee, but i cant figure out how to pixelate the rgb output. i know how to pixelate textures and such, but about rgb not sure.

Comment: Which RGB output do you mean? The _Color_ output of an _RGB_ node? Or _Color_ outputs from some kind of procedural texture? If you know how to pixelate textures, where exactly are you stuck when trying to transfer this to other things? I don't know how you do it, but usually you pixelate by manipulating the texture coordinates. You can do this with procedural textures as well. But if you want this for something like the _RGB_ node, well it just outputs a single color, what do you want to pixelate there? Maybe you can explain a bit further and show what you got and what you want.

Comment: No, its a shader output to rgb(difuse shader)

Comment: Do you want to pixelate in screen-space. or in surface-space? Please clarify with an example illustration of the effect you want to achieve, with the tools provided to insert an image into your post

Comment: Yes, i want to pixelate it in surface space. I am not very familiar with stackExchange(registered just to ask this question) so i dont know how to attach images. But basicaly i want the lighting to be pixel perfect on cubic models.
Unironicaly i found this image on twitter of minecraft shaders that have almost the exact effect i want: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FJb5-09XIAg23qQ?format=jpg&name=small

Answer (score 1):

As you said in the comments (which would have been really useful information in the question by the way), you want to pixelate the output of a *Shader to RGB* node.

The problem with this is, to pixelate you need a frame of reference, a coordinate system because the common understanding of pixelation is separating a texture into larger tiles by averaging the color of the original pixels within a tile.

But the *Shader to RGB* just converts the shading result into a color information, whereas the shading contains shadows, reflections etc. on the surface which are not pixelated. The *Shader to RGB* node itself has no coordinate system since it is not bound to any coordinates. So what kind of coordinates or grid do you want to base your pixelation on?

Either you need an already pixelated texture on the shader which is then plugged into the *Shader to RGB* node (but this will not pixelate any shadows for example, so would only give useful results if you used the pixelated texture on an *Emission* shader), or you will have to give the object itself tiled normals which would then result in some tiled output.

Below is an example for that, but with this setup you have the problem that the normals do not show as the usual rectangular tiles you would expect with a pixelation:

[image: pixelate shader to rgb]

Of course on simple rectangular objects this might look better, like the cube in the example below, on other objects you might want to try *Generated*, but in general this works best with faces that are aligned with the texture coordinates.

[image: pixelated cube]

The render engine seems to have problems when you snap to values that are dividing the object's coordinates without remainder, like when the cube is 2 × 2 m and you choose *Increment* values like 0.1, 0.2, 0.25, 0.5 and so on, this will result in visible artifacts on the facets (the larger the increment, the more apparent the artifacts). They already appear before using the *Shader to RGB* node, but only in *EEVEE* and not in *Cycles* (there you cannot use the *Shader to RGB* node unfortunately). So it is best to set the *Increment* to some odd value (in my example I used 0.21 instead of 0.2).

Comment: Hi, this doesn't really work. When i try to apply this to a cube, the edges look jaggered

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with jagged edges, I've added an example with a cube to my answer. Or do you mean shading artifacts on the facets? I mention them in my addition.

Comment: It looks like this for me

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1203357766174122084/1204078320069910528/image.png?ex=65d36c52&is=65c0f752&hm=6cecb1025502942369d0a5636a400aaf7f97e3781158e694a366b1d6141a8803&

Comment: @СлаваЭгов Oh yes, the shading artifacts on the facets - that's what I mean. On my computer they disappear completely when using some arbitrary values for _Increment_, but your screenshot looks as if this did not help you. Have you tried to use _Object_ instead of _Generated_? Anyway, seems like _EEVEE_ has problems with this, sorry I cannot help with that. You need to use _EEVEE_ for _Shader to RGB_, so I have no idea how to get a workaround.

Comment: I have tried both eevee and cycles, both have problems: 
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1203357766174122084/1204083069699498034/image.png?ex=65d370be&is=65c0fbbe&hm=5af34b179da4acecaff9b9d57bf7e9a25a3c43a8b4bf36a7ab2af65ba3954965&=&format=webp&quality=lossless&width=1065&height=676
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1203357766174122084/1204083069271674950/image.png?ex=65d370be&is=65c0fbbe&hm=55853dcc36158e9b860832318152ffe7e4b541747ac643cb0a16849f512fa34e&

Comment: @СлаваЭгов I do not see any problems in the _Cycles_ screenshot. No artifacts, nothing. But since these are just settings for the normals, what did you expect to see there in _Cycles_? It just makes the surface appear as if it has a faceted bump. And the _EEVEE_ version, is this rendered view or material preview? Just to be clear about that. But as I said, that's just how it is, that's why I hardly use _EEVEE_. And because you cannot easily pixelate something which has no pixels in the first place.